# Помощь в олимпиадной задаче

Tags: python, python-3.x

В одном курином ресторане можно купить:

```
1 ножку + 1 крыло,
1 ножку + 1 бедро,
1 бедро,
2 крыла,
3 крыла.
```

Требуется определить, можно ли купить ровно k крыльев, n ножек и b бедер.

> Написал вот такой код, я думаю, что крыльев точно не должно быть равно 1, т.к. мы можем взять только 2 или 3 крыла, а любое простое число состоит из суммы этих цифр. Походу я что-то не учёл, кто может, исправьте пожалуйста

```
k = int(input())
n = int(input())
b = int(input())

if k==1 and n==0:
    print('NO')
elif k>n:
    n1 = k-n
    if n1!=1:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
else:
    n1 = n-k
    if n1>b:
        print('NO')
    else:
        print('YES')
```